# "can't read:variable is array" error in ns2

Tags: tcl, ns2

In ns2, I declared a simple array using

```
array set ktree {}
```

then I tried to use it as a GOD variable as

```
create-god $ktree
```

but this gives the error

```
can't read "ktree": variable is array
while executing
"create-god $ktree {}"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tcl, `$varName` means “*read from the variable called `varName`*” and is not a general reference to the variable (unlike some other languages, notably Perl and PHP, which do rather different things). Reading from a whole array, instead of an element of that array, is always an error in Tcl.

To pass an array to a command, you pass the *name* of that array in. It's then up to that command to access it as it sees fit. For procedures and methods written in Tcl, it'll typically involve `upvar` to link the array into a local view. (Things written directly in C or C++ have far fewer restrictions as they don't automatically push a Tcl stack frame.)

Note however that the command *must* be expecting the name of an array when you pass that name in. (Good programmers will document this fact, of course.) Whether `create-god` does, I really have no idea; it's not a general Tcl command but rather something that's more specific. (Part of ns2? Or maybe your own code.)

---

### Example of passing in an array

An example of passing in an array by name is the `parray` command that should be part of every Tcl distribution. It's a procedure that prints an array out. Here's the [source code](https://core.tcl.tk/tcl/artifact/46a08300c8d8176d7458394cfc14c22057513eec) without a few boiler-plate comments:

```
proc parray {a {pattern *}} {
    upvar 1 $a array
    if {![array exists array]} {
        error "\"$a\" isn't an array"
    }
    set maxl 0
    set names [lsort [array names array $pattern]]
    foreach name $names {
        if {[string length $name] > $maxl} {
            set maxl [string length $name]
        }
    }
    set maxl [expr {$maxl + [string length $a] + 2}]
    foreach name $names {
        set nameString [format %s(%s) $a $name]
        puts stdout [format "%-*s = %s" $maxl $nameString $array($name)]
    }
}
```

The key thing here is that we first see `upvar 1` to bind the named variable in the caller to a local variable, and a test with `array exists` to see if the user really passed in an array (so as to give a good error message rather than a rubbishy one). Everything else then is just the implementation of how to actually pretty-print an associative array (finding out the max key length and doing some formatted output); it's *just plain Tcl code*.

Comment: @Chhama Yes, well probably. Depends on what you mean by that. Doing justice to what you're asking will take me more than I can fit in a comment; could you ask it as a proper question?

Comment: im not sure it will be accepted as a proper question :) . What im basically trying to do is to create a weight-balanced AVL Tree using tcl without using OTcl. My plan involves structures but i read a structure cannot contain another structure so Im kind of at a loss here.